# Restrict selection in ChoiceBox

Tags: java, javafx

Im having a 5rows with  5columns of ChoiceBox, i want to have a button which only submit the choicebox selected, if there is only one selection per row, which means, submission must be successful if there are 5 selection of the choiceboxes.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, it is not quite clear what you are asking here. Please read the Help Center's guide on [ask] a good question. Then [edit] your question to clarify your question. Including a [mcve] is very important as well.

Comment: The button should invoke a method that processes the selection of all `CheckBox`s. Try to write it and post your code, as advised, for help with it.

Comment: If you change your `CheckBox`s to `RadioButton`s then you can put each row in a `ToggleGroup` to restrict each row to only one choice for example